# How to center icons inside a box

Tags: html, css

I have these boxes that contain social icons at the end of each webpage of my website. I didn't write the code for it because I'm editing a template so I didn't really do anything. However, one of the pages has a messed up box. They all share the same CSS and the HTML for it is the same as on other pages so I can't figure out why this single page is acting up. I've carefully compared the pieces of code on other pages just in case I have mistakenly changed something but there's no difference and now I'm stumped. What can possibly be wrong? My code snippets below, if someone might kindly help me look at it.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<section id="footer">
      <ul class="icons">
        <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-twitter solo"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-facebook solo"><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-google-plus solo"><span>Google+</span></a></li>  
      </ul>
    
      <div class="copyright">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li>&copy; 2022 by Me. All rights reserved.</li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
<style>
footer
    {
        margin-top: 1em;
    }

    br.clear
    {
        clear: both;
    }

    /* Sections/Articles */
    
        section,
        article
        {
            margin-bottom: 3em;
        }
        
        section > :last-child,
        article > :last-child
        {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        section:last-child,
        article:last-child
        {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .row > section,
        .row > article
        {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

    /* Images */

        .image
        {
            display: inline-block;
            border: 0;
        }
        
            .image img
            {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .image.featured
            {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0 0 2em 0;
            }
            
            .image.full
            {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }
            
            .image.left
            {
                float: left;
                margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
            }
            
            .image.centered
            {
                display: block;
                margin: 0 0 2em 0;
            }

                .image.centered img
                {
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    width: auto;
                }

    /* Lists */

        ul.default
        {
            list-style: disc;
            padding-left: 1em;
        }
        
            ul.default li
            {
                padding-left: 1.5em;
                margin-top: 1.5em;
            }       
            
            ul.default li:first-child
            {
                margin-top: 0;
            }

        ul.icons
        {
            cursor: default;
        }   
        
            ul.icons li
            {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            
                ul.icons a
                {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 2.5em;
                    height: 2.5em;
                    line-height: 2.5em;
                    text-align: center;
                    border: 0;
                }
                
        ul.menu
        {
            cursor: default;
        }
        
            ul.menu li
            {
                display: inline-block;
                line-height: 1em;
                border-left: solid 1px #dad9d9;
                padding: 0 0 0 0.5em;
                margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
            }
            
            ul.menu li:first-child
            {
                border-left: 0;
                padding-left: 0;
                margin-left: 0;
            }

        ul.actions
        {
            cursor: default;
        }
        
            ul.actions li
            {
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
            }
            
            ul.actions li:first-child
            {
                margin-left: 0;
            }

        ol.default
        {
            list-style: decimal;
            padding-left: 1.25em;
        }

            ol.default li
            {
                padding-left: 1.25em;
                margin-top: 1.5em;
            }

            ul.default li:first-child
            {
                margin-top: 0;
            }
</style>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Change this  `ul.icons a` to `ul.icons .icon`

Comment: @Dlk that's literally targeting the same thing - how's that going to help?

Comment: Please post the *minimum* amount of code required to reproduce as a **snippet** so we can see the results without having to copy-paste.